# DNS Authoritative Answer Issue

Tags: networking, dns, ip

So I was just doing some studying of DNS and ran across an issue I can't explain (or find an answer to on the good ole Google).

Basically, I was just doing a simple IP lookup for `yahoo.com`. However, none of the IP addresses returned by `nslookup` were resolving correctly in my browser. Here is the output of `nslookup`:

*ex. nslookup of yahoo.com*

[image: nslookup of yahoo.com]

But every one of those IP addresses resolves to a webpage like this:

*ex. yahoo maintenance page*

[image: yahoo maintenance page]

So I figured it might be a problem with my DNS server. So I did a nameserver lookup and used the results from that (shown in the image below) to set my DNS Server in `nslookup`:

*ex. nslookup for yahoo.com nameservers*

[image: nslookup for yahoo.com nameservers]

However, even after doing that, all the IP addresses returned for `yahoo.com` still resolved to that weird maintenance page. Also, even after setting `nslookup` to use one of those namerservers, I'm still not getting authoritative answers back...

*ex. non-authoritative answer*

[image: still no authoritative answers...]

Any ideas what the issue is? Or what I'm doing wrong? I haven't ran into this problem with any of the other sites I do this on.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Sorry I couldn't embed the images btw...my reputation isn't high enough yet

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to include the output text from nslookup instead of using  images. 2) Are you trying to visit Yahoo by going in the IP address directly? That's not going to work....

Comment: Ok will do. I just felt like the images conveyed all the info better

Comment: And yes, why won’t that work? It works with google and other sites

Comment: Do you see "Non-authoritative answer" from domain nameservers even for completely unrelated domains (e.g. google.com or superuser.com)? It might be Yahoo's unusual DNS system that forgets to set this flag, too.

Answer (score 3):

Many web servers are configured to serve multiple sites/domains from the same single IP address (virtual hosting). This requires that the web browser send a "Host:" header saying which site they're trying to load (since the IP address the request was received on is not enough info). HTTP/1.1 made the "Host:" header mandatory, so this is how things have worked for over twenty years now. Filling in the Host header with the IP address still doesn't tell the web server which site you're trying to access. Some web servers may be configured to have a primary/default site to serve when this happens, but others will just serve an error page.

Try telnetting to port 80 on one of those IP addresses and manually entering your HTTP request headers. See what happens when you use yahoo.com in the Host header, and what happens when you just put in the IP address.

Comment: Thanks Spiff. That was the issue. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Also, Spiff I was wondering if you could clarify what you meant by this: "Filling in the Host header with the IP address still doesn't tell the web server which site you're trying to access." -- I thought this WOULD tell the server which site you're trying to access?

Comment: @ubernoob1010 Not if it's multiple websites on a single IP address.